# Select a certain row among the duplicates

Tags: list-manipulation

I have the following problem: I have a (a lot)*3 table, meaning that I have 3 columns, say X, Y and Z, with real values. In this table some of the rows have the same (X,Y) values, but with different value of Z. For instance

```
{{12.123, 4.123, 513.423}, {12.123, 4.123, 33.43}}
```

have the same (X,Y) but different Z. This is a case of multiplicity=2, but in principle it could be higher. What I want to do is to take all the unique rows, AND in case they have multiplicity >1 (i.e. repeated (X,Y)), pick the one with minimum Z value. In the previous example it would be the second one.

I hope I have been clear! Thank you very much indeed!

Comment: `First /@ (SortBy[#, Last] & /@ GatherBy[data, Most])` or more compactly `First /@ (Sort /@ GatherBy[data, Most])`

Comment: @Bob I think you should post that as an answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
data = Table[{x, y, RandomReal[]},
   {x, 3}, {y, 3}, {3}] // Flatten[#, 2] &
```

> {{1, 1, 0.987008}, {1, 1, 0.682772}, {1, 1, 0.923863}, {1, 2,
>   0.464991}, {1,    2, 0.963954}, {1, 2, 0.829995}, {1, 3, 0.773942}, {1, 3, 0.550081}, {1, 3, 
>     0.0821332}, {2, 1, 0.466804}, {2, 1, 0.964716}, {2, 1, 0.679577}, {2, 2, 
>     0.820486}, {2, 2, 0.10238}, {2, 2, 0.810867}, {2, 3, 0.87029}, {2, 3, 
>     0.530354}, {2, 3, 0.91676}, {3, 1, 0.345255}, {3, 1, 0.939562}, {3, 1, 
>     0.456195}, {3, 2, 0.497948}, {3, 2, 0.13677}, {3, 2, 0.544248}, {3, 3, 
>     0.271007}, {3, 3, 0.539826}, {3, 3, 0.927424}}

```
First /@ (SortBy[#, Last] & /@ GatherBy[data, Most])
```

> {{1, 1, 0.682772}, {1, 2, 0.464991}, {1, 3, 0.0821332}, {2, 1,
>   0.466804}, {2,    2, 0.10238}, {2, 3, 0.530354}, {3, 1, 0.345255}, {3, 2, 0.13677}, {3, 3, 
>     0.271007}}

However, since {x,y} are identical in each grouping, then `SortBy[#,Last]&` is equivalent to `Sort`

```
First /@ (Sort /@ GatherBy[data, Most])
```

> {{1, 1, 0.682772}, {1, 2, 0.464991}, {1, 3, 0.0821332}, {2, 1,
>   0.466804}, {2,    2, 0.10238}, {2, 3, 0.530354}, {3, 1, 0.345255}, {3, 2, 0.13677}, {3, 3, 
>     0.271007}}

```
% == %%
```

> True

Answer (score 3):

```
DeleteDuplicates[SortBy[data, Last],( #1[[1]]==#2[[1]]  && #1[[2]]==#2[[2]] & ) ]
```

Explanation:
`data` is your data of the form `{{x1,y1,z1},...,{xn,yn,zn}}`. With `SortBy[#, Last] &` we sort this dataset with respect to the last coordinate, e.g. z.

With `DeleteDuplicates`  you can simply delete duplicate elements of a list. By specifighing a `SameTest` one can define which elements are treated to be equal.

The following `SameTest`

```
#1[[1]]==#2[[1]]  && #1[[2]]==#2[[2]] &
```

says that both x and y-coordinates should be equal so that two elements are treated to be the same.

This is a shorter form of this test:

```
#1[[1;;2]]==#2[[1;;2]] &
```

**EDIT:**
Probably most simple form of this approach:

```
DeleteDuplicates[SortBy[data, Last], Most[#1] ==Most[#2]&]
```

as suggested by [Bob-Hanlon](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/9362/bob-hanlon)

Comment: The `SameTest` could also be written `Most[#1] == Most[#2] &`

Comment: @Bob-Hanlon hey I was not aware of this function!  Thanks for the hint. I'll add this to my answer!

Comment: Very clean, but note that it gets really slow for large lists.

Comment: @2012rcampion interesting, is that because of `DeleteDuplicates`? I can't make a performance test at the moment, because I am on a phone.

Comment: Yeah, I think `DeleteDuplicates` is slow.

Answer (score 2):

Using the new `Association` method `GroupBy`:

```
Append @@@ Normal[GroupBy[data, Most -> Last, Min]]
```

This method is slightly slower than Bob Hanlon's and alephalpha's (and produces identical results), but I thought I'd show off one of the v10 features.

Answer (score 1):

```
Min /@ Transpose@# & /@ GatherBy[data, Most]
```

Or if you're using Mathematica 10:

```
First@*MinimalBy[Last] /@ GatherBy[data, Most]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
f1 = Composition[DeleteDuplicatesBy[Most], SortBy[Last]]

SeedRandom[1]
data = Append @@@ Transpose[{RandomInteger[2,{10,2}], RandomReal[1,{10}]}];
data2 = f1 @ data;
Row[MatrixForm /@ {data, data2}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Alternatively,

```
f2 = DeleteDuplicatesBy[Most] @ SortBy[Last] @ #&;
f1 @ data == f2 @ data
(* True *)
```